# How declare $emit on the index.d.ts file?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, typescript-typings

I'm create my first plugins for vuejs and I'm using Typescript. My problem is when I try use my plugin, because the compiler is show me that ##"Property `$emit` does not exist on type `{ onClick(event: MouseEvent): void; onDoubleClick(event: MouseEvent): void; }`"##

I have create a file index.d.ts in the root with my index.ts. I am usign the following guide [a link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) but I am lost how declate the type for a Standard Event from Vue

```js
// index.d.ts
import Vue  from "vue";

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $emit: typeof Vue.prototype;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't get the problem, i feel too much is missing. Is knowledge of vuejs required?